# My code does not run and i can't seem to get the score to print

Tags: xenocode

```
def tf_quiz():

    user_name
    user_year

print("Welcome to my true or false divison quiz") #welcome message

user_name=str(input("please enter in your name")) #asks/stores user input

user_year=str(input("please enter in your year")) #asks/stores user input

print("all you have to do is type T/F for each question") #explaning the task

print ("12/3 = 4") #asks the question
if correct_ans == "T" : #correct answer
            print ("Correct!") #prints correct if the answer is correct
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "F" : #incorrect answer
            print ("incorrect!")  #prints incorrect if the answer is incorrect

print ("42/6 = 7")
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("incorrect!")  
    
print ("18/3 = 4")
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("incorrect!")  

print ("40/5 = 9")
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("incorrect!") 

print ("90/10 = 9")
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("incorrect!") 

print (" 16/2= 4")
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("incorrect!")

print ("9/3 = 3")
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("incorrect!")

print ("45/9 =5 ")
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("incorrect!")

print ("81/9 = 7")
if correct_ans == "F" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("incorrect!")

print("49/7 = 7")
if correct_ans == "T" :
            print ("Correct!")
            score = score +1
if correct_ans == "F" :`enter code here`
            print ("incorrect!")

#Main program
tf_quiz()
```

I can't print the name and score for the user using this code,
and it also does not run. I have tried multiple different things but i still cannot get it to work no matter what i do to try and fix it. the code also will not run and it will not give me any problems or ways to make it run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'it also does not run'?  What exactly happens with your code?  What is the actual output and the expected output?  What are the sample inputs?  Please also re-edit your code such that it is indented properly.

Comment: when i try to run the code it doesnt run(it doesnt display any of the code that is meant to appear)

Comment: Are those ```if correct_ans ...``` blocks supposed to be outside the ```tf_quiz()``` function?

Comment: i have fixed that but now i need to define correct_ans i have changed the quiz_Q1 = tf_quiz("12/3 = 4", "T") to (print ("12/3 = 4") but i now have a problem with correct_ans not being defined

Comment: Please update your code to include what you've done.

Comment: i have edited it and changed it to my new code

Comment: Please take the time to edit your post such that it's formatted properly (indented properly).

Comment: sorry im really confused by what you men all i need to do is define correct_ans